# How to record audio in background on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, audio-recording

There are so many answers for this questions, but I didn't understand properly how to record audio when the app running in background on iOS? i want to make app like call recording please suggest me how can i do?

Comment: Any existing code of yours you might want to share? You have to show some effort, otherwise this question will be closed.

Answer (score 4):

1) first go to app target > capabilities > background modes
checkmark on Audio and airplay

2) Add the following lines in info.plist file...
Required background modes : App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay.

then record audio and go to background.

Comment: Probably you already know it but it will be ok to add this small information. If you will open any other app then automatically recording will stop.

Comment: If it"s another app, that will record. Correct.

Comment: @lukas_o yes. it's another app.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the Background Modes option adds the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. [See developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. A link only answer might be a good hint, but please add the relevant parts to the answer, because a link can change.